# MongoID find or find_by

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

The MongoID [docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#queries) seem to be pretty clear that I should be able to run this and have it work:

```
Band.find_by(name: "Photek")
```

but at least with MongoID 2.4.11 this gives me a `NoMethodError`.

This, on the other hand, works:

```
Band.find(name: "Photek")
```

It's easy enough to change `find_by` to `find`, but I'm confused what's going on.  Is this a case where my gem version is behind the docs, or what?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Mongoid docs now show you version 3 by default (it's an RC). You want to look at the docs [here](http://two.mongoid.org) for Mongoid 2.

On `find` vs `find_by`, this is from the [upgrade guide](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/upgrading.html) for Mongoid 2 -> 3:

> Model.find and model.relation.find now only take a single or multiple ids. Model.first, Model.last also no longer take arguments. For these use Model.find_by instead.

IOW:

Mongoid 2:

```
Band.find(some_id)
Band.find(name: "Billy Talent")
```

Mongoid 3:

```
Band.find(some_id)
Band.find(some_id, some_other_id)
Band.find_by(name: "Billy Talent")
```